# Problema com evento de clique em botão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar o evento de clique de um botão da classe `btn-remove`, porém, está dando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">  </head>    
    <body>

    <h1>Teste de button</h1>

        <button class="btn-remove" data-id='2'>Deletar</button>

        <script>
            $('.btn-remove').click(function(){

             let id = $(this).attr('data-id');


            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você tem o código do jQuery sendo importando dentro de seu HTML? Esse é um erro clássico de arquivo que não está sendo importado.

Comment: Tenho não amigo, apenas o <script></script>

Comment: se a resposta estiver correta marque como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possíveis causadores de erros:

- Falta a biblioteca

  ```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ```
- Código na posição errada. (no seu caso está correto, embaixo do botão)

Veja seu código funcionando:

```js
 $('.btn-remove').click(function(){

      let id = $(this).attr('data-id');

      console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">  </head>    
    <body>

    <h1>Teste de button</h1>

        <button class="btn-remove" data-id='2'>Deletar</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

A ordem correta é:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">  </head>    
    <body>

    <h1>Teste de button</h1>

        <button class="btn-remove" data-id='2'>Deletar</button>

    </body>
</html>


<script language="javascript">

     $('.btn-remove').click(function(){

          let id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    });

</script>
```

**ou com** [$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> Código incluído dentro `$( document ).ready()` só será executado uma vez que a página Document Object Model (DOM) esteja pronta para executar o código JavaScript.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('.btn-remove').click(function(){

              let id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        });
     });

</script>

<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">  </head>    
    <body>

    <h1>Teste de button</h1>

        <button class="btn-remove" data-id='2'>Deletar</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vlw amigo, tentarei aqui, Deus abençoe!